# Remote Debugging Silverlight Server in IIS7

Tags: silverlight, wcf, remote-debugging

I have a problem on the server side of my Silverlight application.  It's in one of my WCF Services.  The app works fine on my dev machine, but is failing on the test server.  I'd like to find a way to remote debug my service from my dev machine.  Is this possible using Visual Studio 2010?

Since the WCF Service and Server side application is hosted within IIS7, I don't know how to attach to get it started.

Any help is greatly appriciated,

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010:

1. Install the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on the server (MSVSMON.exe)
2. Debug Menu...Attach to process -
3. select the Transport to Remote or Default
4. Select the Qualifier to the server name
5. Select the process to attach to in the Available Processes list and press Attach

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>     
    <sources> 
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" 
              propagateActivity="true"> 
        <listeners> 
          <add name="traceListener" 
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
              initializeData= "c:\temp\WEBTraces.log" /> 
        </listeners> 
      </source> 
    </sources> 
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Read more of this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx